# Python multi-processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a large list containing binary encoded strings that I used to process in a single function before, like so:

```
""" just included this to demonstrate the 'data' structure """
data=np.zeros(250,dtype='float32, (250000,2)float32')

def func numpy_array(data, peaks):
rt_counter=0
    for x in peaks:
        if rt_counter %(len(peaks)/20) == 0:
            update_progress()
        peak_counter=0
        data_buff=base64.b64decode(x)
        buff_size=len(data_buff)/4
        unpack_format=">%dL" % buff_size
        index=0
        for y in struct.unpack(unpack_format,data_buff):
            buff1=struct.pack("I",y)
            buff2=struct.unpack("f",buff1)[0]
            if (index % 2 == 0):
                data[rt_counter][1][peak_counter][0]=float(buff2)
            else:
                data[rt_counter][1][peak_counter][1]=float(buff2)
                peak_counter+=1
            index+=1
        rt_counter+=1
```

I have been reading up on multiprocessing and figured that I wanted to try that to see if I could get a big increase in performance, I rewrote my function into 2 (helper and 'caller') like so:

```
def numpy_array(data, peaks):
    processors=mp.cpu_count #Might as well throw this directly in the mp.Pool (just for clarity for now)
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=processors)
    chunk_size=len(peaks)/processors
    for i in range(processors):
        counter = i*chunk_size
        chunk=peaks[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size-1]
        pool.map(decode(data,chunk,counter))

def decode(data,chunk,counter):
    for x in chunk:
        peak_counter=0
        data_buff=base64.b64decode(x)
        buff_size=len(data_buff)/4
        unpack_format=">%dL" % buff_size
        index=0
        for y in struct.unpack(unpack_format,data_buff):
            buff1=struct.pack("I",y)
            buff2=struct.unpack("f",buff1)[0]
            if (index % 2 == 0):
                data[counter][1][peak_counter][0]=float(buff2)
            else:
                data[counter][1][peak_counter][1]=float(buff2)
                peak_counter+=1
            index+=1
        print data[counter][1][10][0]
        counter+=1
```

The program runs but only uses 100-110% of CPU (according to top) and once it should be finished it throws `TypeError: map() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)` at me, could anyone with some more experience with multiprocess give me a hint as to what things to look out for (that could cause the TypeError)? What might be causing my low cpu usage?

**-- Code after incorporating answers --**

```
def decode((data,chunk,counter)):
    print len(chunk), counter
    for x in chunk:
        peak_counter=0
        data_buff=base64.b64decode(x)
        buff_size=len(data_buff)/4
        unpack_format=">%dL" % buff_size
        index=0
        for y in struct.unpack(unpack_format,data_buff):
            buff1=struct.pack("I",y)
            buff2=struct.unpack("f",buff1)[0]
            if (index % 2 == 0):
                data[counter][1][peak_counter][0]=float(buff2)
            else:
                data[counter][1][peak_counter][1]=float(buff2)
                peak_counter+=1
            index+=1
        counter+=1

def numpy_array(data, peaks):
    """Fills the NumPy array 'data' with m/z-intensity values acquired
    from b64 decoding and unpacking the binary string read from the 
    mzXML file, which is stored in the list 'peaks'.

    The m/z values are assumed to be ordered without validating this
    assumption.

    Note: This function uses multi-processing
    """
    processors=mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=processors)
    chunk_size=int(len(peaks)/processors)
    map_parameters=[]
    for i in range(processors):
        counter = i*chunk_size
        chunk=peaks[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size-1]
        map_parameters.append((data,chunk,counter))
    pool.map(decode,map_parameters)
```

This latest version 'works' so far that it fills the array in the processes (where the array contains values) but once all processes are done accessing the array yields zero values only because each process gets a local copy of the array.

Comment: First argument to multiprocessing.Pool defaults to the number of processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

Note that `pool.map` takes a function and a list of parameters for that function for each call.  In your original example you are just calling it in the `numpy_array` function.

The function must only have one argument, hence the packing of the arguments into a tuple and the rather odd looking double brackets in `decode` (which is called tuple unpacking).

```
def numpy_array(data, peaks):
    processors=4
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=processors)
    chunk_size=len(data)/processors
    print range(processors)
    map_parameters = [] # new
    for i in range(processors):
        counter = i*chunk_size
        chunk=peaks[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size-1]
        map_parameters.append((data,chunk,counter)) # new
    pool.map(decode, map_parameters) # new

def decode((data,chunk,counter)): # changed
    for x in chunk:
        peak_counter=0
        data_buff=base64.b64decode(x)
        buff_size=len(data_buff)/4
        unpack_format=">%dL" % buff_size
        index=0
        for y in struct.unpack(unpack_format,data_buff):
            buff1=struct.pack("I",y)
            buff2=struct.unpack("f",buff1)[0]
            if (index % 2 == 0):
                data[counter][1][peak_counter][0]=float(buff2)
            else:
                data[counter][1][peak_counter][1]=float(buff2)
                peak_counter+=1
            index+=1
        print data[counter][1][10][0]
        counter+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in your `numpy_array` function:

```
for i in range(processors):
    counter = i*chunk_size
    chunk=peaks[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size-1]
    pool.map(decode(data,chunk,counter))
```

The problem is that you're calling `map` sequentially so you're only running one process at a time.  Also, I don't think you're calling `map` correctly as you're doing `pool.map(f(*args))` when the signature is `map(f, ['list', 'of', 'data'])`.

I would use a partial so that you don't create copies of `data` as I assume that array is quite large or could be larger in the future.

This should be:

```
import functools
decode_with_data = functools.partial(decode, data)
args = []
for i in range(processors):
    counter = i * chunk_size
    chunk = peaks[1*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size-1]
    args.append(chunk, counter)
pool.map(decode_with_data, args)
```

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 just for pointing me towards functools.partial. I never heard of that and it seems like a really neat library